# Why does the area come back as 0?

Tags: c++, pi

Here's the code.

```
int a;
int pi = 3.14;
int area;
int main()
{
    cout << "Input the radius of the circle ";
    cin >> a;

    a *= a *= pi >> area;

    cout << "The area is " << area;


}
```

Comment: 3 is a fairly inaccurate estimate for pi.

Comment: This code is so broken it's not even funny any more. For starters: Do you realize that `cin >> ...` (and `cout << ...`) is a very special case and `<<` (and `>>`) mean something very different in about every other context, including in `pi << area`? You're lucky you get 0 though, you might as well get anything.

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points . `a *= a *= pi >> area;` has _undefined behavior_.

Comment: Does that even compile? I though double isn't implicitly convertible to int.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Yes, any floating point type may legally be converted to any integer type. The behaviour is only undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.

Comment: @Charles: Yet an error of about 0.1416 is hardly responsible for the wrong result here ;-)

Comment: As a buddy of mine would say...too clever by 1/2. a = ( a * a ) * pi;

Comment: @Matt Bettinson: This code shows that you don't yet have a good grasp of some of the fundamentals of C++, I suggest that you get a good beginners book and work through the first few chapters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @FredOverflow: Hence a comment; not an answer.

Comment: @delnan: Actually, globals are guaranteed to be initialized to 0.  (but there's no good reason to be using global variables here either)

Comment: I wonder if C++ is not the first OP's programming language. If so, could you name it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of a circle is pi * r * r therefore you would want to do;

`a = a * a * pi`

Hope that helps

and they all would need to be floats.

Answer (score 13):

The `>>` operator when used with numbers is right shift, not assignment.  You want something like

```
area = a * a * pi;
```

*Update*

You also need to use a floating point type or your answer won't be what you expect.

```
float a;
float pi = 3.14f;
float area;
```

Comment: Lets waste some space. Lets use double as our floating point default.

Comment: @Martin: isn't that premature pessimization ? ;)

Comment: No it isn't. The time needed to debug rounding errors is far to long.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough patience to decipher your strange code. How about just `area = a * a * pi`?

Answer (score 6):

Your code doesn't make any sense.

`pi`(and all your other variables) need to be double or float,... not int. An int can only contain an integral number. And `pi` is obviously not integral.

`a *= a *= pi >> area;` should be `area = a * a * pi;`

`>>` is a bitshift, not an assignment to the right side
`*=` is multiply assign and not just multiply. i.e. it is similar to `left=left*right`

Comment: +1 For writing what I wrote, but in a far more coherent manner. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't do what I think you wanted it to do. You don't assign to variables with `>>`; that is only for stream extraction (and bitshifting).

Also, `a *= a *= pi` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Also, you want floating-point values, not `int`. An "int" pi is just 3.

Also, you should have error checking on your stream extraction!

Try:

```
int main()
{
    const float pi = 3.14;
    float a;

    cout << "Input the radius of the circle ";
    if (!(cin >> a)) {
         cout << "Invalid radius!";
         return 1;
    }

    float area = (a * a * pi);

    cout << "The area is " << area;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int pi = 3.14;
```

Wrong datatype. Assigning double value to `int`? That's wrong.

Write this:

```
double pi = 3.14;
```

And likewise, change other datatypes to `double` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `int`, or integer, for all your variables.  You want to use `double`s or even `float`s.  (`double`s are more precise).

Comment: I think you were downvoted because it does not cover all problems with the code (e.g. the attempted assignment to `area` using the `>>` operator).

Answer (score 1):

All your variables are declared as int, which simply drops any fractional portion assigned to it. To work with floating-point values, use double instead.

Also, your equation in almost incomprehensible. Not sure what you're trying to do there.